# LibGDX - load file in AssetManager from local storage

Tags: android, libgdx, android-assets

I have a model that is in local storage (`/data/user/0/com.myapp/files/model.g3db`). I want to load this model in my `AssetManager` to use it later. 
If use standard method like `assetManager.load("model.obj", Model.class);`, it gets a file from the `assets` folder that is a part of project. It doesn't suit me. So, I tried to use `AssetDescriptor` to specify the file:

```
FileHandle fh = Gdx.files.local("model.g3db");
if(fh.exists()) Gdx.app.log("file", "exists");
else Gdx.app.log("file", "not exists");

AssetDescriptor<Model> ad = new AssetDescriptor<Model>(fh, Model.class);
assets.load(ad);
```

Output:

```
I/file: exists

Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load dependencies of asset: model.g3db
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.handleAsyncLoader(AssetLoadingTask.java:121)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.update(AssetLoadingTask.java:90)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.updateTask(AssetManager.java:507)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:381)
                  at com.myapp.EngineCore.render(EngineCore.java:226) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphicsLiveWallpaper.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphicsLiveWallpaper.java:220) 
                  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1571) 
                  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1270) 
               Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: model.g3db
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.async.AsyncResult.get(AsyncResult.java:46)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.handleAsyncLoader(AssetLoadingTask.java:119)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.update(AssetLoadingTask.java:90) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.updateTask(AssetManager.java:507) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:381) 
                  at com.nolesh.android.livewallpapers.iamrich.EngineCore.render(EngineCore.java:226) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphicsLiveWallpaper.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphicsLiveWallpaper.java:220) 
                  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1571) 
                  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1270) 
               Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: model.g3db
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.UBJsonReader.parse(UBJsonReader.java:56)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.loader.G3dModelLoader.parseModel(G3dModelLoader.java:65)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.loader.G3dModelLoader.loadModelData(G3dModelLoader.java:61)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.ModelLoader.getDependencies(ModelLoader.java:75)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.ModelLoader.getDependencies(ModelLoader.java:35)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:64)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:34)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.async.AsyncExecutor$2.call(AsyncExecutor.java:58)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
               Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: model.g3db (Internal)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:77)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:151)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.UBJsonReader.parse(UBJsonReader.java:54)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.loader.G3dModelLoader.parseModel(G3dModelLoader.java:65) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.loader.G3dModelLoader.loadModelData(G3dModelLoader.java:61) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.ModelLoader.getDependencies(ModelLoader.java:75) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.ModelLoader.getDependencies(ModelLoader.java:35) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:64) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:34) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.async.AsyncExecutor$2.call(AsyncExecutor.java:58) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
               Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: model.g3db
                  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
                  at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:374)
                  at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:348)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:75)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:151) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.UBJsonReader.parse(UBJsonReader.java:54) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.loader.G3dModelLoader.parseModel(G3dModelLoader.java:65) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.loader.G3dModelLoader.loadModelData(G3dModelLoader.java:61) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.ModelLoader.getDependencies(ModelLoader.java:75) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.ModelLoader.getDependencies(ModelLoader.java:35) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:64) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:34) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.async.AsyncExecutor$2.call(AsyncExecutor.java:58) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

When I move this model to the `assets` folder of my project, it successfully loads.

So, my question is how to load model to the `AssetManager` from the local storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a perfect solution, but it works. `AssetManager` has a constructor that accepts `FileHandleResolver` as a parameter.

```
AssetManager assets = new AssetManager(new LocalFileHandleResolver());
```

It's not an ideal solution, because if you are going to use mixed assets from the local storage and the internal one, that you need to create `AssetManager` for each one.